# Unit testing Angular JS controllers

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My Jasmine unit test is as follows

```
describe('controllers', function () {
    'use strict';
    beforeEach(module('myapp.controllers'));

    angular.mock.module('myapp.controllers', function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('$localStorage', $localStorage);
    });

   it('should have a creationController', inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, localize) {
       var scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
       var localize = localize;
       var myCtrl1 = $controller('creationController', {
           $scope: scope,
           localize: localize
       });
       expect(myCtrl1).toBeDefined();
   }));

});
```

When I try to execute the test I'm getting the following error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/unpr?p0=localizeProvider%20%3C-%20localize
```

There is a dependency called as "localize" being used in the controller. However I'm unable to inject that in to this unit test.

Any idea how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried doing beforeEach(module('myapp.controllers', '<moduleOfLocalizedService>')) ?

Comment: @JorgeSainz tried out your suggestion and now Im getting the following error  Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/modulerr?p0=localize&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.20%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dlocalize%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fresources%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F89bd1c3ea71433b7675321fdede5e2f2323e15a0%3A20%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fresources%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3F89bd1c3ea71433b7675321fdede5e2

Comment: Can you create a codepen or sth? I have an example using jasmine 2.0 and angular 1.2.20 in codepen so you can fork it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apAue

Comment: Try: angular.mock.inject(function($injector) { localize = $injector.get("localize"); });

Answer (score 0):

injector look for `_componenrToBeInjected_` for injection . If you have a service name `localized` (Are you sure you have one ?) then for injection use 
`_ localize_` so your it block should look like this .

```
it('should have a creationController', inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, _localize_) {
       var scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
       var localize = _localize_;
       var myCtrl1 = $controller('creationController', {
           $scope: scope,
           localize: localize
       });
       expect(myCtrl1).toBeDefined();
   }));
```